SQL injection with LIKE Clause (bWAPP Get/Search Medium Level)
I was trying to perform some SQL Injection on bWAPP application. I a running test on medium level where query is like this.
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%".$(title)."%';

User will send the data in get request through query parameter title.
In addition, the input is sanitized using addslashes() function in PHP.
I am unable to use ' or " and \ also. I am tried the hex values but didn't work.
The % , and _ are allowed as input by user.
How can I perform SQL injection in this situation?


Assuming it's PHP, it will cause lots of syntax errors. 2. given input is utf-8 encoded and sanitized using addslashes() and query works with regular input, you CAN NOT prerform an SQL injection on this query.


What database connector are you using?  If you let the connector do the substitution, it knows the escaping rule, with prepare and execute.

@TimRoberts are you sure you understood this question correctly?

if user uses PDO you cant inject sql otherwise you can use tools like sqlmap to test injection

@MohammadrezaEsmaeeli if user uses PDO you cant inject sql Well that is only true if the coder has used PDO PROPERLY
